# show multiple choice questions with answers to users

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql database called `question` with fields `questionid`, `name`, `choice1`, `choice2`, `choice3`, `answer`.

I entered 4 questions in the database but need to show only one random question to the users.

please suggest me. thanks

Comment: what you have tried?? use rand function while fetching data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RAND()` function.

### Query

```
SELECT * FROM question  
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56ea36/1)

Comment: Thats great....Now i realize I am Very poor in programming.. thanks.

Comment: @PrasantKalita: Mark it as answer if you don't mind